# sql query date time

Tags: sql, mysql, date, time

i have a datestamp field in my table structure.
using sql, i want to find any user who registered in yesterdays date using these time range.

eg: 
2010-02-06 14:00:00
2010-02-07 10:00:00

i will be running this query once a day to grab users.

so tomorrow will be:
2010-02-07 14:00:00
2010-02-08 10:00:00

the day after tomorrow will be:
2010-02-08 14:00:00
2010-02-09 10:00:00

etc, etc.

select distinct * from users where loggedTime...

not sure how to query the date range? any ideas thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server

```
where loggedTime between
   DATEADD(hour, 14, DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY,0,getdate()))) and
   DATEADD(hour, 34, DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY,0,getdate())))
```

MySQL

```
where loggedTime between
   curdate() + interval 14 hour and
   curdate() + interval 34 hour
```

Comment: i dont want to change the query all the time for the actual day as these are changing; the time doesn't change so this wouldn't work.

Comment: i got an error when i run it. 
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'getdate()))) and
   DATEADD(hour, 34, DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY,0,getdate()))' at line 2

Comment: @Chocho:  please, next time, let us know what DBMS you're using from the start.  `curdate()` will work in MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate

Comment: ok will do, still i am getting mysql error:
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM users
WHERE loggedTime
BETWEEN DATEADD(
HOUR , 14, DATEADD(

DAY , 0, DATEDIFF(
DAY , 0, curdate( ) )
)
)
AND DATEADD(
HOUR , 34, DATEADD(

DAY , 0, DATEDIFF(
DAY , 0, curdate( ) )
)
)

Comment: That's because it's SQL Server syntax. I added MySQL syntax.